# Unable to resolve cinterop IOS import in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have followed the Kotlin documentation for adding iOS dependencies.  In my case the dependency is a pre-compiled framework provided through a third party.  So I have followed the case for framework without cocoapod.

I placed my MyFramework.def file in /src

```
language = Objective-C
modules = MyFramework
package = MyFramework
```

Then I added the following to the build.gradle.kts in the Kotlin object
```

```
ios {
    binaries {
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }
}
iosArm64() {
    compilations.getByName("main") {
        val JWBLe by cinterops.creating {
            // Path to .def file
            defFile("src/nativeInterop/cinterop/MyFramework.def")

            compilerOpts("-framework", "MyFramework", "-F/Users/user/Projects/MyFramework/ios/SDK")
        }
    }

    binaries.all {
        // Tell the linker where the framework is located.
        linkerOpts("-framework", "MyFramework", "-F/Users/user/Projects/MyFramework/ios/SDK")
    }
}
sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting
    val commonTest by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
            implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
        }
    }
    val androidMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
        }
    }
    val androidTest by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
        }
    }
    val iosMain by getting
    val iosTest by getting
}
```

Then I build the project.  The library does indeed get seen and I see that in External Libraries, there is a `shared-cinterop-MyFramework.klib`

However, when I try to import this package into my code under `src/iosMain/kotlin/com.example.testapp.shared/platform.kt`
I get unresolved error for the library.  It seems like I should also need to add something to sourceSets? But I am unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I got to notice that the Gradle script is incorrect. In this case, the `iosArm64` target was declared twice - by the [target shortcut](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-share-on-platforms.html#use-target-shortcuts) and once again where you configure the cinterop. To avoid this duplication, it would be better to configure cinterop like that:

```
ios()
    val iosArm = targets.getByName("iosArm64") as  org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget
    // A bit dirty cast, but as I'm sure iosArm64 is the Native target, it should be fine. Needed to make highlighting below work as expected.
    iosArm.apply {
        compilations.getByName("main") {
            val JWBLe by cinterops.creating {
                // Path to .def file
                defFile("src/nativeInterop/cinterop/MyFramework.def")

                compilerOpts("-framework", "MyFramework", "-F/Users/user/Projects/MyFramework/ios/SDK")
            }
        }
        binaries.all {
            // Tell the linker where the framework is located.
            linkerOpts("-framework", "MyFramework", "-F/Users/user/Projects/MyFramework/ios/SDK")
        }
    }
```

However, this adjustment won't help with accessing cinterop bindings from the `iosMain`. In the current state of [commonizer](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/native/commonizer/README.md), it can share only [platform libraries](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/platform_libs.html). So anyway, moving all code utilizing those bindings into the `src/iosArm64Main` folder is the best option available at the moment. Here go an issue from the official tracker to upvote and subscribe - [Support commonization of user-defined libraries](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40975).

Answer (score 1):

So after some playing around I found the answer.

The dependency was set for a module of iosArm64 which is not available to the iosMain.

I created another folder src/iosArm64Main and placed the source file there.  At that point it was able to resolve the library.